# How do I create a secure application load balancer with docker compose ecs integration?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, https, amazon-ecs

I am struggling to find a way to use docker compose ecs integration to create an application load balancer which uses HTTPS and a certificate. I have a domain name and a certificate for it issued by the AWS Certificate manager, but cannot find how to modify my docker-compose.yml to specify that I want my ALB to use it and forward the connection to my application which is listening on port 8080. The only reference I have been able to find is https://techsparx.com/software-development/docker/docker-ecs/load-balancer/https.html, which suggests that you need to jump through hoops backwards with cloudformations.

This page is 18 months old, so I am hoping there is now a more straightforward way to achieve this. Can anbody help?